# What does the wavenumber refer to when solving the Poisson equation with fourier transforms?

Tags: fourier-transform, matlab, laplacian, poissons-equation

I am working on my senior project in college on $n$-body gravitational simulations solving the Poisson equation using Fast Fourier Transforms. After realizing that I did not understand the math well enough, I decided to play around with scilab (similar to matlab and I believe even uses the same scripting language) to see if I could figure it out. I solved for potential (or tried) and plotted using this equation...

$$\nabla^2 (\hat{\phi}e^{i(k_xx)}) = -(k_x^2)(\hat{\phi}e^{i(k_xx)})
\\= 4\pi G \hat{\rho} e^{i(k_xx)}$$
So...
$$ -(k_x^2)\hat{\phi} = 4 \pi G\hat\rho \\
\hat\phi = -\frac{4\pi  G  \hat\rho}{k_x^2}$$

This is not my own work. This is based off of an observablehq.com notebook by Ricky Reusser. You can find the whole explanation as well as their 2d simulation [here](https://observablehq.com/@rreusser/2d-n-body-gravity-with-poissons-equation?collection=@rreusser/writeups).

Next is my scilab attempt at a 1D model, the script and the resulting graph. (I apologize to any matlab veterans out there. This is my first time using anything like matlab, so please forgive the cluckiness)

```
s = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 0 0];
c = 0:28;

y=fftshift(fft(s));
k_x = 2 * %pi * c/ 29;
y=-(4 * %pi * 4.300E-03 * s)/ k_x * k_x;

new_y = ifftshift(ifft(y));

f = 29 *(0:(56/2))/29;
n = size(f,'*')
clf()
plot(f, new_y(1:n))
```

Picture of the Graph:[image: Picture of the Graph]

Issue 1: even though my mass is over to the right, the location of the potential does not change.

Issue 2: I should be getting numbers with just real components out, but when I print out the data this is not the case.

I am pretty sure that the issue is with the wave number $k_x$ and despite many hours of search I have not found a way to understand what is going on with the wave number. So any insight into what is causing these issues and what k actually mean more concretely than that it is related to $\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ would be great!

Comment: Do not use $*$ for multiplication, especially when working with PDEs and the Fourier transform. Just write the stuff out as a product without a symbol. $*$ typically refers to convolution and appears very frequently when solving PDEs, often with Fourier transform techniques.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thanks! I just fixed it. I didn't think of that and I was trying to avoid the hat notation from overlapping with other variables.